# How to Print a List of Values?

Tags: python

```
print("Hello. Please Proceed to Enter a Range of Numbers")
first = int(input("please enter the first number in the range: "))
last = int(input("please enter the last number in the range: "))

numlist=list(range(first,last)
```

I get an error expected eof while parsing. When I add in `print(numlist)`
it adds an additional error.

Comment: If this is _the exact code_, you don't have closing paranthesis.

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis on your last line.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make the list inclusive of 20? It only printed [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]

Comment: increase your stop value by 1. `range(first, last+1)`

Comment: You need parenthesis on last line if not, you get `TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement on line (...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("Hello. Please Proceed to Enter a Range of Numbers")
first = int(input("please enter the first number in the range: "))
last = int(input("please enter the last number in the range: "))

numlist=list(range(first,last)) #FTFY
for x in numlist:
   print(x)
```

Essentially what this does is after numlist is declared, it traverses it and prints out every value on a new line

Your main problem was that you were missing the second RPAREN on the numlist declaration